# I want to preform a check to ensure a user doesn't upload the same data object to a collection in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check to ensure that a user will not upload an object twice to a collection in firebase, I am a student and really new to swift and in general my coding is probably pretty poor.

So basically I have set up a two checks before I'm allowing a user to upload a piece of data to firebase, one is that the picture contains a QRcode, and two that they have no already uploaded with the same information encoded on the QR. I have included my code below. I think my problem lies with the async nature of querying the database, but I'm lost at how to fix it.

thanks for any help.

```
@IBAction func registerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {        
    if let features = detectQRCode(photoImage), !features.isEmpty{
        for case let row as CIQRCodeFeature in features{
            print(row.messageString ?? "noQRFound")
            bandageSerialNum = row.messageString
            if checkIfQrfound(row.messageString) {
                if checkIfBandageAlreadyRegistered(row.messageString) {
                    errorLabel.text = "Bandage has already been registered, please register a new bandage, or return to take an updated photo" //not working yet, i think something to do with the async nature of querying the database
                } else {
                    uploadToDatabase()
                    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
      
            }  else{
                errorLabel.text = "The QR code was not read correctly, please re-take your photo and try again"
            }                                
        }
    }
}

func checkIfQrfound(_ QrString: String?) -> Bool{
    if QrString != nil {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func checkIfBandageAlreadyRegistered(_ bandageQR: String?) -> Bool {
    
    var isBandageAlreadyRegistered: Bool = false
   
    
    if let currentBandage = bandageQR {
        db.collection(K.FStore.bandageCollectionName).whereField(K.FStore.bandageID, isEqualTo: currentBandage).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let e = error {
                print("err: \(e.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
                    if snapshotDocuments.count > 0 {
                        isBandageAlreadyRegistered = true
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    return isBandageAlreadyRegistered
}`
```

Comment: How many times does the loop iterate through `features`?

Comment: I thought it would only be once as I am expecting only one QR in the image, but I will double check ASAP!

Comment: Ohh, are you trying to hint that maybe I should my check outside of the loop?

Comment: You can check within the loop, I just want to know if it’s possible that there may be multiple iterations in the loop. Or can we rewrite this code to handle just one?

Comment: First thing is firebase is asynchronous and you cannot return a value *after* a firebase call. I am linking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67116310/return-statement-runs-too-fast-swift-with-firebase) because it contains links to a LOT of links and information about that topic. e.g. this code `return isBandageAlreadyRegistered` will run before the data is returned from Firebase. One option is a completion hander using @escaping to handle this issue. A second more basic option is to perform the save *within the closure* when it determines the object is not a dup.